# Linq2Twitter MediaEntity: How to access more than one ImageURL

Tags: c#, twitter, linq-to-twitter

why is it that the linq2Twitter API only stores one image as a MediaURL in the Entity class even there are surly two images in a particular tweet?

This is the tweet "https://t.co/VoxCtVl2k1" that I am debbugung in the screenshot. It has two pictures but the fully qualified URL is only for the first one accessible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look under `ExtendedEntities`, which is a newer object in the Twitter API.

On Search queries, the Twitter API has a bug that hasn't been resolved. Please visit and like the following issue in their forums:

https://twittercommunity.com/t/search-tweets-endpoint-and-extended-entities/31655

LINQ to Twitter does support the include_entities parameter, like this:

```
        Search searchResponse =
            await
            (from search in twitterCtx.Search
             where search.Type == SearchType.Search &&
                   search.Query == searchTerm &&
                   search.IncludeEntities == true
             select search)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

As I said earlier, this isn't working. A potential work-around is to use a Status/Lookup query, like this:

```
        List<Status> tweets =
            await
            (from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
             where tweet.Type == StatusType.Lookup &&
                   tweet.TweetIDs == "460788892723978241,462758132448362496,460060836967768064"
             select tweet)
            .ToListAsync();
```

To make this work, find all of your tweets in the search response that have media and collect their IDs. Then combine those into a comma-separated list and assign to TweetIDs. Remember that you can only do a lookup of 100 IDs at a time.

Comment: I did a Status/Show query. What query are you using?

Comment: Search searchResponse =
                await
                (from search in twitterCtx.Search
                 where 
                 search.Type == SearchType.Search &&
                       search.Query == query
                 select search)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync();